# RxJs Observable<string> vs Observable<string[]>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm having a hard time getting my head around RxJS Observables, though I've used the observable pattern in a number of different situations throughout my life. Here's some code:

```
    const observable: Observable<Response> = createdElswhere();
    let test1: Observable<string>;
    let test2: Observable<string[]>;

    test1 = observable.map(r => r.json());
    test2 = observable.map(r => r.json());
```

Response.json() returns an array of data - usually objects that will be mapped to a typescript object, but they're just strings in this case:

```
[  
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3",
    "test4"
]
```

When I subscribe to the `test1` or `test2` properties (in an angular view template, or manually in code using `.subscribe()` for example), the observable generic type doesn't seem to make any difference to the framework. The items are displayed exactly the same, even though the 'data' inside the observable is different (one is an array, the other is an array of observable strings).

Can anyone explain the difference between `Observable<string>` and `Observable<string[]>`, and give me an example of how they *should* be used?

Comment: you should use <string> if  an event gives you a single string, and <string[]> if the event returns an array of strings. In this case your observable seems to be returning an array of strings. What matters is what the response contains. :)

Comment: This is what I thought. However, all my observables are defined as Observable<type> (rather than Observable<type[]>, but all my data is returned from the back-end as arrays; I'm getting no TS warnings, and any subscription code doesn't seem to care how I define it.

Comment: the types you define are only at compile time, at runtime all type information is lost. Also what the server returns should be the type of your observable, the type you write there are there to decribe that, they dont mandate it. I think the problem here is that you are just typing your observables wrong.

Comment: I would have expected the runtime to pick that up - that my json array can't be converted to an Observable<type>

Comment: there is no runtime type checking with typescript, if that's what you are looking for you're using the wrong language.

Comment: It does not return what you are expecting, it will return what it was supposed to. you have to check the structure of Response and then define the observable type (either string or string[] or anything else)

Answer (score 1):

`Observable<string>`
meansthat you are creating a observer for type string

`Observable<string[]>`
means that you are creating a observer for array of string

since you are coding in typescript it just a typecheck which helps your compiler when you will wrongly try to assign the variable. since type script are compiled to javascript which doesnt have type check so it dosent matter what you assign the value with

eg:
**In typescript **

`let k:int;`

`k=r.json().val;`

**In javascript compiled code is equal to**

`var k;`

`k=r.json().val;`

so if `r.json().val` return int then k will become int and k is string it will become string

Answer (score 0):

`Observable<string>` is the type of observables where each emitted value is supposed to be a string.
`Observable<string[]>` is the type of observables where each emitted value is supposed to be an array of strings.

Whatever type you assign to an observable doesn't change what the observable will actually emit. That depends only on how the observable is constructed. If you do `observable.map(r => r.json())` and `r.json` returns a string, the resulting observable will emit strings, if it returns an array of strings, the resulting observable will emit arrays of strings.

Said that, if `r.json` has a type signature like `(r: Response): string[]`, Typescript should complain that `test1`'s type is incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

As the others explained, the type argument (the one you put between `< >`) indicates to typescript what will be the type of the data emitted by this observable.

As said as well, at runtime, this has no difference, since typescript runs the type-checking at build time.

That being said, you are seeing no difference between `test1` and `test2` because `.json()` returns `any` ([refer here](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.response.html#json)), so typescript can't complaint if you are casting it to `string` or `string[]`.
It will, on the other hand, complaint if you try to use a string method (e.g. `replace`) on something you have typed as `string[]` for example.